# Python Regex pattern not being matched

Tags: python, regex, file

I'm trying to get some regex to parse some values stored in a set of lua files, each line looks something like one of these two lines

1. `ITEM.ID = 'item_clock';\r\n`
2. `ITEM.Cost = 150;\r\n`.

when I run my regex pattern on the first line I get an expected result

```
>>> re.search("ITEM.(?P<key>[a-zA-Z]\w) = (?P<value>.*);", line).groupdict()
{'key': 'ID', 'value': "'item_clock'"}
```

however when I run it on the second line, I don't get a Match object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The regex looks for `ITEM.` followed by a letter then followed by **exactly one** word character (the `\w` in the regex).

You probably meant something like `ITEM.(?P<key>[a-zA-Z]\w*)`... (note the added asterisk). This will look for `ITEM.` followed by a letter then followed by **zero or more** word characters.

Also, it's a good idea to use [raw strings](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) for regular expressions to avoid hard-to-spot bugs:

```
r"ITEM.(?P<key>[a-zA-Z]\w*) = (?P<value>.*);"
```

(note the `r` prefix).

Comment: thanks, that has worked perfectly! I'm just starting to get my head around regex.

Comment: @H4Z3Y: I've just added a note about raw strings. I think it's a good habit to get into.

Comment: +1 for raw strings.  This is such a good idea that python should really just enforce it, since that seems to be a big part of their design philosophy anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer is right.  Minor tweaks...

- escape the "." after ITEM to mean a "." and not just anything
- usually a good idea to allow for more than one space (or no spaces) around the "="

  r"ITEM\.(?P<key>[a-zA-Z]\w*) *= *(?P<value>.*?) *;"

Comment: I think escaping the spaces just as you did with the dot is a good idea too.

Comment: Agreed the best is to replace the " \*" with "\s\*" ... better regex but a little less readable ... like regex is ever readable

Comment: Actually I meant `\ ` (with the space character), but I think in the end there is indeed a lot of "space" (pun intended) for personal preference ;o). So it would become
`r"ITEM\.(?P<key>[a-zA-Z]\w*)\ *=\ *(?P<value>.*?) *;"` (formatting removed one space :o(